# Post another person's tweets into Facebook group?

Tags: facebook, twitter, automation

How can I re-tweet another person's posts into my Facebook group?

I am interested on doing this automatically, since I basically want to re-tweet of all this person's tweets.

Comment: I'd expect IFTTT to have a recipe that would work.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this natively.

The closest will be a Twitter to Facebook Pages recipe as the person above commented https://ifttt.com/recipes/search?q=twitter+to+facebook&ac=false

Comment: Trying to use IFTTT now to do this, there are options for Facebook and Facebook Pages: neither appears to create posts on a Facebook Group?